# String split after a number and symbol

Tags: java, string, split

I have a sample string eg

`"ZZZ-1234567890-from ABC-2 DEF"`

I need the output to be:

```
"from ABC-2 DEF"
```

All the sample strings are in the format

`"ZZZ-numbers-Strings"`

I need to get the string part after

`"ZZZ-numbers-"`

I tried using `split()` but could not solve it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

After reading your question again, knowing that your `String`s are in the format

"ZZZ-numbers-Strings" and you want everything after "ZZZ-numbers-"

Then you can do a split with a regex pattern of "ZZZ-\d+-".  This will result in a 2-element array and you want the results at index 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "ZZZ-1234567890-from ABC-2 DEF";
    String[] split = data.split("ZZZ-\\d+-");
    System.out.println(split[0]); 
    System.out.println(split[1]); 
}
```

Results:

```
(blank line for split[0])
from ABC-2 DEF
```

### OLD ANSWER

This looks more like a job for `substring()` and `indexOf()` as long a "from" exists only once in your `String` and you want to capture everything after "from" including "from".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "ZZZ-1234567890-from ABC-2 DEF";
    System.out.println(data.substring(data.indexOf("from"))); 
}
```

Results:

from ABC-2 DEF

Answer (score 1):

According to your format you probably want to remove the first part "ZZZ-numbers-"

using replaceAll with regex do the trick (inspired by @Shar1er80 answer):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "ZZZ-1234567890-from ABC-2 DEF";
    System.out.println(data.replaceAll("^.{3}[-][0-9]+[-]","")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use `String.split("ZZZ-\\d+-")[1]`